# SQL SUM Time of multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, sum

I need some help on an SQL statement. I'm trying to SUM up time on 1 to 2 rows. So far the output looks like this:

```
workingdate    cin      typecin    cout    typecout   rn    sum
---------------------------------------------------------------------
2021-05-03     07:49    K          13:31   G          1     05:42:00
2021-05-03     14:01    K          16:17   G          2     02:16:00
2021-05-04     07:52    K          13:36   G          1     05:44:00
2021-05-04     14:04    K          16:22   G          2     02:18:00
...
```

This is my Code so far:

```
WITH CTE AS 
    (   SELECT chip_num, chip_user_id, chip_user,
            CONVERT(DATE,[date]) workingdate,
            (CASE WHEN [type] = 'K' THEN format([date], 'HH:mm', 'de-DE' ) ELSE NULL END) [cin],
            (CASE WHEN [type] = 'K' THEN type ELSE NULL END) [typecin],
            subtypein,
            (CASE WHEN [type] = 'G' THEN format([date], 'HH:mm', 'de-DE' ) ELSE NULL END) [cout],
            (CASE WHEN [type] = 'G' THEN type ELSE NULL END) [typecout],
            subtypeout,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY chip_num,CONVERT(DATE,[date]), [type] ORDER BY [date]) rn
        FROM app_terminal1
    ),
    CTE1 AS
    (
        SELECT chip_num, chip_user_id, chip_user, workingdate, 
        LEFT(CONVERT(TIME(4),MIN([cin]),114),5) [cin],
        LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),MIN([typecin]),114),5) [typecin],
        LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),MAX([subtypein]),114),5) [subtypein],

        LEFT(CONVERT(TIME(4),MIN([cout]),114),5) [cout],
        LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),MIN([typecout]),114),5) [typecout],
        LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),MAX([subtypeout]),114),5) [subtypeout],

        FORMAT( DATEDIFF(MINUTE, LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),MIN([cin]),114),5), LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),MIN([cout]),114),5))/60, '00', 'en-US' ) as diffHour, 
        FORMAT( DATEDIFF(MINUTE, LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),MIN([cin]),114),5), LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),MIN([cout]),114),5)) 
        - (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),MIN([cin]),114),5), LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),MIN([cout]),114),5))/60) * 60, 
        '00', 'en-US' )as diffMin,
        rn
        FROM CTE
        where chip_user_id = @ChipUserId and YEAR(workingdate) = @Year and MONTH(workingdate) = @Month 
        GROUP BY chip_num, chip_user_id, chip_user,workingdate,  rn
    ),
    CTE2 AS
    (
    select *, CONVERT(time,  case when diffHour IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE CONCAT(diffHour, ':', diffMin) end) as sum from CTE1
    )

    select * from CTE2
```

The output I need:

And I need something like this where the `sum` gets summed up for the whole day inside `sumDay`. But it is important to do something with the `rn` because the entries can vary. Sometimes there is only 1 row, or maybe 3 Rows!

```
workingdate    cin      typecin    cout    typecout   rn    sum         sumDay
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
2021-05-03     07:49    K          13:31   G          1     05:42:00
2021-05-03     14:01    K          16:17   G          2     02:16:00    07:58:00
2021-05-04     07:52    K          13:36   G          1     05:44:00
2021-05-04     14:04    K          16:22   G          2     02:18:00    08:02:00
...
```

SAMPLE DATA:

Tablescheme:

```
name - varchar(255)
serial - varchar(255)
chip_user_id - varchar(255)
chip_user - varchar(255)
chip_num - varchar(255)
date - datetime
type - varchar(255)
subtypein(255)
subtypein(255)
```

Sample Insert into:

```
insert into app_terminal1 (name, serial, chip_user_id, chip_user, chip_num, date, type, subtypein, subtypeout)
VALUES 
('Test', 'Test',    '999',  'Test Test',    '9092090',  '2021-03-05 07:49:12.000',  'K',    NULL,   NULL),
('Test', 'Test',    '999',  'Test Test',    '9092090',  '2021-03-05 13:31:12.000',  'G',    NULL,   NULL),
('Test', 'Test',    '999',  'Test Test',    '9092090',  '2021-03-05 14:01:12.000',  'K',    NULL,   NULL),
('Test', 'Test',    '999',  'Test Test',    '9092090',  '2021-03-05 16:17:12.000',  'G',    NULL,   NULL),

('Test', 'Test',    '999',  'Test Test',    '9092090',  '2021-04-05 07:52:12.000',  'K',    NULL,   NULL),
('Test', 'Test',    '999',  'Test Test',    '9092090',  '2021-04-05 13:36:12.000',  'G',    NULL,   NULL),
('Test', 'Test',    '999',  'Test Test',    '9092090',  '2021-04-05 14:04:12.000',  'K',    NULL,   NULL),
('Test', 'Test',    '999',  'Test Test',    '9092090',  '2021-04-05 16:22:12.000',  'G',    NULL,   NULL)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using. What is the output that you want to achieve: the table at the start of your question or the table at the end?  Please supply sample source data that matches the sample result you want to achieve

Comment: The table I want to achieve is the one at the end. How do I provide a sample source data? 
An Insert into?

Comment: yes. please include the table schema & sample data in `insert into ...` format

Comment: Ok I've done it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make some changes to your query. Basically I avoid formatting date / time inside the query. If you need to format it to the required format, do it at the very last `select` statement, but not inside the `cte`, it complicates any calculation required on the date or time.

To calculate your `sum` column, use `DATEDIFF()` use `MIN()` and `MAX()` on `[date]`

```
DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(CONVERT(TIME(0), [date])), MAX(CONVERT(TIME(0), [date])))
```

And to calculate the `sum` column and for `sumDay` use the window function

```
SUM(diffTotalMin) OVER (PARTITION BY workingdate)
```

To convert to the require time format `HH:MM` you can use `DATEADD(MINUTE, diffTotalMin, 0)`

---

```
WITH 
CTE AS
(
    SELECT  chip_num, chip_user_id, chip_user,
            CONVERT(DATE,[date]) AS workingdate, [date], [type],
            subtypein, subtypeout,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY chip_num, CONVERT(DATE,[date]), [type] 
                                  ORDER BY [date]) AS rn
    FROM    app_terminal1
),
CTE1 AS
(
    SELECT  chip_num, chip_user_id, chip_user, workingdate,
            MIN(CONVERT(TIME(0), [date]))  AS cin,
            MIN(CASE WHEN [type] = 'K' then [type] end) AS [typecin],
            MAX(subtypein) AS subtypein,
            MAX(CONVERT(TIME(0), [date]))  AS cout,
            MIN(CASE WHEN [type] = 'G' then [type] end) AS [typecout],
            MAX(subtypeout) AS subtypeout,
            rn,
            DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(CONVERT(TIME(0), [date])), 
                             MAX(CONVERT(TIME(0), [date]))) AS diffTotalMin
    FROM    CTE
    GROUP BY chip_num, chip_user_id, chip_user, workingdate, rn
),
CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            diffTotalMin / 60 AS diffHour,
            diffTotalMin % 60 AS diffMin,
            CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(MINUTE, diffTotalMin, 0)) AS [sum],
            CASE WHEN rn = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY chip_user_id , workingdate) 
                 THEN CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(MINUTE, SUM(diffTotalMin) OVER (PARTITION BY workingdate), 0)) 
                 END AS [sumDay]
    FROM    CTE1
)
SELECT  *
FROM    CTE2
WHERE   chip_user_id = @ChipUserId 
AND     YEAR(workingdate) = @Year
AND     MONTH(workingdate) = @Month;
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bd120b98e989d16658ff24562bb43167)

Comment: Thats actaully pretty good, wait i'll try it out

Comment: Thats weird.. I put the exact same code in a new function but it doesn' calculate the sumDay

Comment: What do you mean by `doesn' calculate` ? Try the dbfiddle demo, it is working

Comment: if I `select * from fnGetTerminalTimes4(05,2021, 999)` sumDay is NULL

Comment: I mean I put the exact same dbfiddle code inside mssql but sumDay is NULL

Comment: use the dbfiddle link that i posted, add in your function and share the link here

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=eb88afae9d6539582c1af6c35038b117
The funny thing is it works in dbfiddle

Comment: see [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7ab35643435c0e6644b77c522d0d8d75), I converted it to a table value function

Comment: I inserted your exact same function `fnGetTerminalTimes5` called it with `select * from fnGetTerminalTimes5(999, 2021, 05)` and sumDay still shows NULL. 
I don't get it

Comment: Most probably it is your data. put the same data in dbfiddle and try

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3d23d7da8840d8e21fcceb4b79a47118 I corrected the data and dbfiddle works. Mssql says NULL

Comment: try use the exact same data in your database in dbfiddle

Comment: Its the exact same data. Here is an image https://imgur.com/a/ImCsZvi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232683/discussion-between-squirrel-and-timebreaker900).

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. You can use left join to join the `sum` per working day,

```
    WITH CTE AS 
        (SELECT chip_num, chip_user_id, chip_user,
                CONVERT(DATE,[date]) workingdate,
                (CASE WHEN [type] = 'K' THEN format([date], 'HH:mm', 'de-DE' ) ELSE NULL END) [cin],
                (CASE WHEN [type] = 'K' THEN type ELSE NULL END) [typecin],
                subtypein,
                (CASE WHEN [type] = 'G' THEN format([date], 'HH:mm', 'de-DE' ) ELSE NULL END) [cout],
                (CASE WHEN [type] = 'G' THEN type ELSE NULL END) [typecout],
                subtypeout,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY chip_num,CONVERT(DATE,[date]), [type] ORDER BY [date] desc) rn
            FROM app_terminal1
        ),
        CTE1 AS
        (
            SELECT chip_num, chip_user_id, chip_user, workingdate, 
            LEFT(CONVERT(TIME(4),MIN([cin]),114),5) [cin],
            LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),MIN([typecin]),114),5) [typecin],
            LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),MAX([subtypein]),114),5) [subtypein],
    
            LEFT(CONVERT(TIME(4),MIN([cout]),114),5) [cout],
            LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),MIN([typecout]),114),5) [typecout],
            LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),MAX([subtypeout]),114),5) [subtypeout],
    
            FORMAT( DATEDIFF(MINUTE, LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),MIN([cin]),114),5), LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),MIN([cout]),114),5))/60, '00', 'en-US' ) as diffHour, 
            FORMAT( DATEDIFF(MINUTE, LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),MIN([cin]),114),5), LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),MIN([cout]),114),5)) 
            - (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),MIN([cin]),114),5), LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),MIN([cout]),114),5))/60) * 60, 
            '00', 'en-US' )as diffMin,
            rn
            FROM CTE
            where chip_user_id = @ChipUserId and YEAR(workingdate) = @Year and MONTH(workingdate) = @Month         
            GROUP BY chip_num, chip_user_id, chip_user,workingdate,  rn
        ),
        CTE2 AS (
            select *, CONVERT(time,  case when diffHour IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE CONCAT(diffHour, ':', diffMin) end) as sumTot from CTE1
     ) 
    select t1.*, 
               + right('00'+ cast(t2.tot%3600/60 AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) + ':'
               + right('00'+ cast(((t2.tot%3600)%60) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) + ':'
               + '00' as sumDay     
    from CTE2 t1
    left join
        (select workingdate, sum(datediff(minute, '00:00:00', sumTot)) as tot from CTE2
                group by workingdate) t2 on t2.workingdate = t1.workingdate and t1.rn = 1
    order by workingdate, cin
```

Try this [dbfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bbf97/37)

Comment: Thanks!
But it gives me some errors 2x `Ambiguous column name workingdate` and `The operand data type time is invalid for the sum operator` and `The rn column was given several times for "CTE2".`

What can I do about it?

Comment: @Timebreaker900, i updated my answer, if could provide sample script for the data, much better

Comment: I put in sample data

Comment: @Timebreaker900, my query is working but trying to get results, you can check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bbf97/17

Comment: What its almost correct.. I renamed the last rn to rn2. But it switches the entries upside down.

Comment: @Timebreaker900, try again

Comment: @Timebreaker900, i updated the formatting, this query is good to go http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bbf97/37

Comment: Can u reverse the rn? currently it is 2 to 1.. but it should be 1 to 2

Comment: @Timebreaker900, i just realized that you already have the rownumber, so I reused it, try this updated query